# match everything inside of * with no whitespaces

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want a regex to have the following behaviour:

```
*test and test* -> match ok
* test and test* -> match NOT ok
*test and test * -> match NOT ok
* test and test * -> match NOT ok
```

I was using this regex to get it working: `\*[^\s](.*?)[^\s]\*`
But the problem is, in group #1, it cuts the first and last letter, so instead of having a match `test and test`, I end up with `est and tes`, I need to keep both first and last letter while also having whitespace in between the words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `[^\s]` actually matches a char, there are 2 of them so it matches (not captures) 2 characters.

The negated character class should be inside the capture group right after the asterix, and repeat it 1 or more times to not match an empty string.

If you want to exclude matching an asterix as well `[^\s*]` and match everything inside the `*` without leading or trailing spaces:

```
\*([^\s*]+(?:\s+[^\s*]+)*)\*
```

The pattern in parts:

- `\*`  Match `*`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s*]+` Match 1+ times any chars other than a whitspace char or `*`
  - `(?:\s+[^\s*]+)*` Optionally repeat 1+ whitespace and again the first character class
- `)` Close group 1
- `\*` Match `*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mHi1vM/1)

Comment: This is the right answer as it doesn't enforce 2 characters between `*`s

Answer (score 0):

You just don't have the first and last letter inside your capture group (denoted by the parenthesis).

Try this: `\*([^\s].*?[^\s])\*`

Comment: Note that this will not match `*t*`